# ZSH Autocompletion: Display value A, use value B

Tags: scripting, zsh, completion

When using `compdef` for ZSH completion, I would like to display a "nice" name to a user (e.g. a device name) and when it is selected, a different value is injected (e.g. device serial number / UUID).

How can this be done with `_arguments` / `_alternative` / `_describe`?

Specifically, I have function `list-devices` that will return `( devA devB devC )`, and a separate shell script that will convert e.g. `devA` into `UUID1234`.  I want the user to be able to select `devA`, and have `UUID1234` appear on the command line.